# Why are there two diffrent full screen editors?

Tags: wp-editor

In the WP editor there is a full screen button. It has shortcut `ALT+SHIFT+G`.
When the button is pressed it shows a different full screen editor then when the shortcut is used.

I tried this on multiple 3.4.1 installations, one of them had no plugins to interfere.

Why is this?

**EDIT**
its a bug: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21197

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21197

Using the shortcut pulls up the TinyMCE fullscreen editor rather than the custom wordpress fullscreen editor.

Update 13. July 2012: Fixed in [Changeset 21266](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/21266).

Comment: I know that now. its my ticket :)